# R 3.0.1 package build warning

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm building R packages in R 3.0.1 on a Windows machine, using Rtools30 and the 'Build' tools associated with RStudio, which I assume is tied in with devtools (which is up-to-date). My typical process to build a package is:

1. Load All
2. Reoxygenize
3. Build & Reload
4. Check
5. Build Source Package

If everything goes without errors or warnings, I then:

```
    install.packages("foo.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Since upgrading to R 3.0.1, I now get this warning:

```
   Warning in install.packages : 
      foo.tar.gz is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I also tried before installing, and it did not get rid of the warning:

```
    options(install.packages.check.source = FALSE)
```

Also, I notice this warning when I open the devtools library:

```
    WARNING: Rtools 3.0 found on the path at c:/Rtools is not compatible with R 3.0.1.
```

Which is weird, Rtools 3.0 is suppose to be good from R >2.15.1 to R 3.0.x

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Isn't this a devtools message? It seems like an over-zealous complaint, since RTools (as of 2013-06-09) is at 3.0 and R is at 3.0.1 so there's not much for the user to do.

Comment: What happens when you try install from the command line: `R CMD INSTALL foo.tar.gz` ?

Comment: Command line works just fine! The 'Warning in install.packages' messages comes directly after install.packages call...which is a basic R function (not devtools, right?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is RStudio specific, as they wrap and/or changed a lot of functions from the utils for better integration. The problem lies with a call to `getDependencies()` to check for dependencies. But that function will also check whether the original package exists on CRAN and throws the given warning when it doesn't. A package you just built on your own computer is obviously not on CRAN, hence the warning.

In the source of the native `install.packages()`, `getDependencies()` isn't called in case you build from source or install from a different repository respectively. RStudio on the other hand calls `getDependencies()` before it passes everything on to the native `install.packages()` function.

This has to my knowledge no further effects, apart from confusing people. I didn't find a way to conveniently get rid of this in RStudio, as `suppressWarnings()` doesn't work in this context due to the complex way RStudio deals with this.

In a basic R console, you shouldn't have any problem.

So for the time being, I'd just ignore this and hope the RStudio team finds time to take care of this minor glitch.

Comment: For reference, this is reported to RStudio here: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/5811-problem-installing-local-packages