# tryCatch not catching error produced by install.packages within RStudio

Tags: r, try-catch, package, rstudio

Consider the following usage:

```
tryCatch(log("a"), error = function(e) NULL)
#NULL
```

Now I'm trying to do essentially the same, but in a more complicated fashion. I have two network repositories, and I'd like to install packages from the second if the first is not available for some reason. Here's how I do it:

```
pkg_location <- c("file://main_repo", "file://extra_repo")
lapply(pkg_location, function(repo)
{
  tryCatch(install.packages("my-cool-package", 
                            contriburl = repo, dependencies = TRUE),
           error = function(e) NULL)
})
```

And I'm expecting a list of `NULL`s. However, the error is not suppressed:

```
Installing package into ‘...’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file '//extra_repo/PACKAGES', 
    probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

It seems like `install.packages` somehow ignores the mechanism. How is that possible, why is that happening and how can I approach the problem?

Here's `sessionInfo`, probably worth noting I'm running RStudio 0.98.977.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: It trapped the error for me. What version of R are you using?

Comment: Please restart and include `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski Added `sessionInfo` and ran again of a fresh session, still the same.

Comment: it also ignores `suppressMessages()` and `suppressWarnings()`. i think it has something todo with that it is not a native R function

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about RStudio's printing of caught errors.

Comment: @Thomas, Not sure that I see this as a suitable reason to close....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RStudio does not exectute the normal install.packages but instead does its own thing:

look at the code in RStudio:

```
> install.packages
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x3e4b478>
> .rs.callAs
function (name, f, ...) 
{
    withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(f(...), error = function(e) {
        cat("Error in ", name, " : ", e$message, "\n", sep = "")
    }), warning = function(w) {
        cat("Warning in ", name, " :\n  ", w$message, "\n", sep = "")
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    })
}
<environment: 0x3bafa38>
```

weird code, it recalls itself ...
i was expecting a `.Primitive()` somewhere

```
> sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

but it is an ugly RStudio hack. if you look at install.packages in normal R you get:

> head(install.packages) # it is really long :P
>   1 function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), contriburl = contrib.url(repos, 
>   2     type), method, available = NULL, destdir = NULL, dependencies = NA,
>   3     type = getOption("pkgType"), configure.args = getOption("configure.args"),
>   4     configure.vars = getOption("configure.vars"), clean = FALSE,
>   5     Ncpus = getOption("Ncpus", 1L), verbose = getOption("verbose"),
>   6     libs_only = FALSE, INSTALL_opts, quiet = FALSE, keep_outputs = FALSE,
>   ....

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is indeed a non-native override from RStudio.

Comment: eeugh yeah if you do the same thing in normal R you get something different... wonder why this hack was needed.

Comment: so I guess a solution would be to use `utils::install.packages` @tonytonov

Comment: that appears to work for me, though i still want to know the reason for this hack. (till that time i will add a nice negative comment in my code cursing rstudio for the piece of .... well you know :)  )

Comment: there is a little bit of explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817095/r-3-0-1-package-build-warning) and [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200650403-problem-installing-local-packages)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest closing as off-topic because this is an RStudio problem. Basically, `tryCatch` is catching the error, but RStudio's error handler prints the error anyway. Thus the reason you're getting a return value:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

This means `tryCatch` works. RStudio just prints caught errors weirdly.

Comment: I've checked in plain console and it works as expected. Never thought RStudio is the one to blame. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespaced invocation:

```
utils::install.packages()
```