# Catch Error/Warning from Install.Packages() - R

Tags: r, try-catch

I am trying to use tryCatch in R to catch warning message of the `install.packages()` and replace it with my own, however, it seems there is something wrong.

Here is what I did,

```
tryCatch({
          install.packages("pkg1")
         },
error=function(e)e,

warning=function(w)w
)
```

However, when I run it, the default message pops up regardless of my tryCatch effort.

Output:

```
Installing package into ‘\\psf/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘pkg1’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

**Questions1:** How to enforce install.packages to use my messages in tryCatch?

**Question2:** How to stop commands like install.packages from echoing message to the console?

**UPDATE**: There is no value in `e` or `w` after execution and warning/error status.

**UPDATE 2**: From comments below, I think its not bad to look at a working example of tryCatch in R. In below example, we must source a file from "components/testfile.R", however, due to spelling mistake (a in camponent), it fails to open the file and hence throws a warning error that we can catch. See below pls.

```
tryCatch({source("camponents/testfile.R")},warning=function(w)w)
```

Upon execution of the above code, the standard warning message of the 'source' command is thrown as below:

> simpleWarning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding): cannot open file 'camponents/testfile.R': No such file or directory>

I expect this behaviour from install.packages(). But, it does not behave this way.
Thanks.

Comment: For question 2, the `quiet` option in `install.packages` may help

Comment: What is the output of `e`?

Comment: @MaxPD the problem is that even though there is a warning or error, nothing is thrown as `e` or `w`.

Comment: @Dylan: I already tried it, but no change. It seems its 'quite' is ignored.

Comment: What is the output of `e`? Or What is the value of `e`? From where did you get it? What did you assign to it? Does that make sense?

Comment: @MaxPD, to my understanding, `e` or `w` must take the value from the install.packages() command not me. I cannot and should not feed it. The only issue I see here, is that install.packages() command does not throw anything in the form of warning or error. I do the same thing with other commands like source("some file") and it does catch error. But not for install.packages()

Comment: @MaxPD, see update pls.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975111/570918